# Insert Mergefield conditionally based on other Mergefield - MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge, field-codes

In MS Word '16, I'm trying to insert a Mergefield based on a Mergefield, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

{ IF { MERGEFIELD A * MERGEFORMAT } = "RP2"  "{ MERGEFIELD B * MERGEFORMAT }" "{ MERGEFIELD C * MERGEFORMAT }" }

In short, if field A = RP2, then return field B, else return field C.

Comment: What is your data source? This logic might be better handled in Access, if that is where the data comes from.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do it in Access.  I'm creating consumer letters to pull data from an application that requires this type of setup to be completed in Word.

I have no problem conditionally inserting a string of text based on a mergefield, but I can't seem to make it work when the return value is to be a mergefield.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The curly brackets represent field braces, which you must insert by pressing Ctrl+F9 (you can't type them).

1. Press CTRL+F9
2. Type IF
3. Press CTRL+F9
4. Type "MERGEFIELD" and the name of the field
5. Go outside the inner brackets
6. Type the operator and the comparative
7. Then the true and false options quoted

It should look like this:

```
{IF { MERGEFIELD A } = "RP2" "«B»" "«C»" }
```

Comment: https://support.getconga.com/Conga_Composer/Creating_Composer_Templates/Word_Templates/Advanced_Word_Templates/How_to_Create_IF_Fields_in_a_Microsoft_Word_Template